# Energy Risk Quant--Any discussion boards for energy related quant topics?

Tags: option-pricing, risk-management, value-at-risk

Any discussion boards for energy related quant topics? Like VaR in energy portfolio, and pipeline option pricing.. just want to know where is the best discussion board for such energy specific topics.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quant.SE! While I have not seen many energy-related topics here on the site, for me, this would definitely be in scope here! So whatever you find, stick around and ask questions here as well. A lot of the techniques used in asset management apply more or less directly to the energy sector too afaik...

Comment: @elephant2015. I too would be interested in any related forums on this topic. What's wrong with posting related topics to SE Quant?

Answer (score -1):

Take a shot, probe around in this one. I don't know how well it is maintained. I saved it to favorites a while back, don't remember why.

http://marcoagd.usuarios.rdc.puc-rio.br/main.html#contents

Comment: While energy related, this looks like a personal webpage and not a discussion board (which is what the OP was asking for).